# How to check decimal boundaries on Danish server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I maintain an application on danish server and I need to check a texbox and make sure the value is greater than 1 and less than 26 . The problem is some people use a , for a decimal and some use a normal decimal. I have tried the code below but it doesn't work on the danish server, but it works great locally. Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(d_m.Text))
            {                   

                if (Convert.ToDouble(d_m.Text) < 1 ||  Convert.ToDouble(d_m.Text) > 25)
                {
                    if (checkfields == false) Response.Write("<tr><td></td><td><font color='red'><b>\"Ship draught\" must be a number greater than 0 and less than 25.</b></font></td></tr>");

                    requeredFieldsMissing = true;

                }
            }
```

Comment: Stop treating numbers like text. But if you must, use `Convert.ToDouble(string, IFormatProvider)`

Comment: @JamesZ are you perhaps mistaking the comma as a thousands separator to that of comma as a decimal separator?  Its the latter that is in question here.

Comment: the commas are being used as a decimal but some people use decimals as decimals too. They want me to code so they can use either.

Comment: Try sth like `decimal.Parse(d_m.Text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: @paqogomez No, comma is the decimal separator and space is the thousand separator -- and dates are DD.MM.YYYY, but that's quite off topic ;)

Comment: Thanks Giorgos that got it to accept the decimal on the sever but not the comma. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following. It successively tries to parse the text as a double, using in descending order of preference

- The current culture on the box,
- the danish culture
- the invariant culture

The first culture to successfully parse the value wins. Here's the code:

```
static double? String2Double( string text )
{
  CultureInfo[] acceptableCultures =
  {
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture            , // prefer the current culture on the box
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo( "da-DK" ) , // then the Danish culture
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture          , // and finally, we'll try the invariant culture
  } ;
  double? value = null ;

  for ( int i = 0 ; i < acceptableCultures.Length && !value.HasValue ; ++i )
  {
    CultureInfo ci = acceptableCultures[i] ;
    double      v ;
    bool        parsedSuccessfully = double.TryParse( text , NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint , ci , out v ) ;

    value = parsedSuccessfully ? v : (double?)null ;

  }

  return value ;
}
```

Then you can say something like:

```
double? userValue = String2Double( GetUserTextFromTextBox() ) ;
if ( !userValue.HasValue ) throw new ArgumentException( "that's not a number!" );
if ( userValue < 1.0 || userValue > 26.0 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( "value must be between 1.0 and 26.0 inclusive" ) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(d_m.Text))
        {                   
            var num = Convert.ToDouble(d_m_Text.Replace(',', '.'));
            if (num < 1 ||  num > 25)
            {
                if (checkfields == false) Response.Write("<tr><td></td><td><font color='red'><b>\"Ship draught\" must be a number greater than 0 and less than 25.</b></font></td></tr>");

                requeredFieldsMissing = true;

            }
        }
```